# how to update or refresh the wp user object?

Tags: users

If I have the wp user object instantiated what is the proper way to update the value of a particular key if it changes during the course of a script? For example, lets say I have this somewhere in my code near the beginning of the script:

```
echo $current_user->display_name;//lets say this returns 'sometestname'
```

Then I do something here to change the value of display name in the wp_users table. Let's say I change the display_name to 'someothertestname' using wpdb->query .

```
echo $current_user->display_name;//still would result in 'sometestname'
```

What should I be doing here? Is this where wp_cache comes in? How do I update the value in the current object? Or do I?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the current user (as your code fragment shows), you'd call `get_currentuserinfo()` again.

[Codex page for `get_currentuserinfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)

Comment: Really? Is there's no way to just update that one key? That seems like a waste to have to reload all of that data even though it's just one key that needs updating.